# How to modify class data through tests?

Tags: python, class, testing, pytest, luigi

I have this luigi task with its required input being 'test_file.txt'. I want to change the required input through testing the class. I need to change the input so that I can test the functionalities of the class with a file. I tried the code below, but the printed result is still the initial path-'test_file.txt'. How can I change the path only in testing? (to get 'data.json' as the printed result.

```
import pytest
import luigi


class LuigiToBeTested(luigi.ExternalTask):
    def requires(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("test_file.txt")


def test_Luigi():
    class_instance = LuigiToBeTested()
    class_instance.requires().path = 'data.json'
    print('/////', class_instance.requires().path) #to get data.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 solutions for you

1. `test_luigi_1` - Intercept (via function) all calls to initialize a new object of `luigi.LocalTarget` and replace the input file name.
2. `test_luigi_2` - Same with 1, but via subclass
3. `test_luigi_3` - Instead of patching as done in 1 and 2, redesign your source code to be testable by allowing [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This is the more extensible way and also more future proof.

   a. [Ask for things, Don't look for things (aka Dependency Injection / Law of Demeter)](https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html)

   b. [Fixing the Client API: Dependency Injection](https://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters)

   c. And many many more references on why this is the preferred way.

```
import luigi
import pytest


class LuigiToBeTested(luigi.ExternalTask):
    def requires(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("test_file.txt")


class LuigiToBeTested2(luigi.ExternalTask):
    def requires(self, file_name):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(file_name)


@pytest.fixture
def amend_local_target_func_based(mocker):  # The <mocker> fixture is from pytest-mock. Install via <pip install pytest-mock>.
    orig = luigi.LocalTarget

    def fake(file_name):
        print(f"Intercepted initialization of luigi.LocalTarget via function. The file {file_name} might be replaced.")

        # If you only want to replace 'test_file.txt' but not the other files, then use this.
        # Otherwise, remove this if and just read from 'data.json' always.
        if file_name == 'test_file.txt':
            file_name = 'data.json'

        return orig(file_name)

    mocker.patch('luigi.LocalTarget', new=fake)



@pytest.fixture
def amend_local_target_class_based(mocker):
    class LocalTargetStub(luigi.LocalTarget):
        def __init__(self, file_name):
            print(f"Intercepted initialization of luigi.LocalTarget via subclass. The file {file_name} might be replaced.")

            # If you only want to replace 'test_file.txt' but not the other files, then use this.
            # Otherwise, remove this if and just read from 'data.json' always.
            if file_name == 'test_file.txt':
                file_name = 'data.json'

            super().__init__(file_name)

    mocker.patch('luigi.LocalTarget', new=LocalTargetStub)


def test_luigi_1(amend_local_target_func_based):
    class_instance = LuigiToBeTested()
    print('/////', class_instance.requires().path) #to get data.json


def test_luigi_2(amend_local_target_class_based):
    class_instance = LuigiToBeTested()
    print('/////', class_instance.requires().path) #to get data.json


def test_luigi_3():
    class_instance = LuigiToBeTested2()
    print('/////', class_instance.requires('data.json').path) #to get data.json
```

```
$ pytest -q -rP
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_luigi_1 _______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercepted initialization of luigi.LocalTarget via function. The file test_file.txt might be replaced.
///// data.json
______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_luigi_2 _______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercepted initialization of luigi.LocalTarget via subclass. The file test_file.txt might be replaced.
///// data.json
______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_luigi_3 _______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
///// data.json
3 passed, 1 warning in 0.07s
```

Comment: You can use the same concept as `amend_local_target_func_based`. Just change the `luigi.LocalTarget` to `pandas.read_excel` and also the file names. I believe it should also work.

Comment: I updated the code with a working one in https://www.codepile.net/pile/mEGZmZXQ Can you see it? Does it work on your side now?

Comment: For existing patches, you might need to look at the library you are using. Like if you are using [boto3](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/), there is a test library [moto](https://pypi.org/project/moto/) which provides builtin patches ready for use. Otherwise, you can do things manually as we did here. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) (or [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html)) for usage.